# Algoritmo No deterministico Para un problema

Tags: algoritmos

Dado un conjunto A de enteros y un entero s, el problema de suma exacta consiste
en determinar si existe un subconjunto B ⊆ A tal que los elementos de B suman s.
Necesito escribir un algoritmo polinomial no determinıstico para este problema.

Realice esto pero no se si cumpliría.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int []numeros= {1,2,3,4};

    int []elegidos= new int [numeros.length];
    System.out.println(buscarSubconjunto(numeros,0,numeros.length,4,elegidos));

    for(int i=0;i<elegidos.length;i++)
    if(elegidos[i]==1)
        System.out.println(numeros[i]);

}
static boolean buscarSubconjunto(int []cifras, int j,int cantidadDeElementos,int k,int elegidos[]){

    boolean temp;
   if(j==cantidadDeElementos)// (* no hay más números en el conjunto *)
     return false;

    if (k==0)
    return true;

    if(cifras[j]>k)// (* el número sobre el cual se está decidiendo es mayor que el objetivo *)
     return buscarSubconjunto(cifras,j+1,cantidadDeElementos,k,elegidos);

    elegidos[j] =1;//(* registra que el número cifras[j] va en el subconjunto solución *)
    temp = buscarSubconjunto(cifras,j+1,cantidadDeElementos,k-cifras[j],elegidos);

    if (temp)
     return true;

    elegidos[j] = 0;// (* registra que el número cifras[j] no va en el subconjunto solución *)
     return buscarSubconjunto(cifras,j+1,cantidadDeElementos,k,elegidos);
}
```

Comment: Pero intentaste algo? en algun lenguaje? Tene en cuenta que aca no se hacen ejercicios, salvo que demuestres que intentaste algo y te trabaste en una parte en particular.

Comment: Si, acabo de editar.

Comment: ok.. que lenguaje es? puede ser java o C#.. si cumpliria con que? en tal caso, que requisitos debe cumplir? como los validaste?

Comment: Si se puede decir que es un algoritmo no determinista. Y es Java

Comment: no parece para nada. No hay nada aleatorio en el y por lo tanto hay un solo resultado posible. Vos que pensas al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []numeros= {1,2,3,4,5};
    boolean []elegidos=new boolean[numeros.length];
    boolean solucion=false;
    int k=6;
    while(solucion==false && suma(numeros)>=k)
    {
        solucion=solucion(numeros,elegidos,k);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<elegidos.length;i++)
    {
        if(elegidos[i]==true)
        System.out.println(numeros[i]);

    }

}

static int suma(int []numeros)
{
    int suma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++)
        suma+=numeros[i];
    return suma;
}
static boolean solucion(int []numeros,boolean[]elegidos,int k)
{

    for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++)
    {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        // Producir nuevo int aleatorio entre 0 y 99
        boolean intAleatorio = aleatorio.nextBoolean();

        elegidos[i]=intAleatorio;
    }
    int suma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<elegidos.length;i++)
    {

        if(elegidos[i]==true)
        suma+=numeros[i];
    }


    return suma==k;
}
```